# HERE API: using app_id and app_code from backend when secured against frontend domain

Tags: here-api

I have a separate frontend (single page application) which is utilizing HERE places API autosuggest feature. However, rest of the application logic which accesses HERE REST APIs is located at the backend side. These services are located on different cloud instances.

I can protect the API credentials by using the frontend SPA domain in "Secure app credentials against a specific domain" in the HERE project page. This blocks the API usage from the backend side. Is there a way to protect the credentials against both services?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HERE Serverless Apps approach. They provide security of AppID and AppCode: because it is in a central cloud Serverless Application being copied and used in every client application. Read more about it here https://www.here.com/en/aws-serverless.

Update: If you are not able to use Serverless, you can also add up to 10 allowed domains in your project in developer site.

Comment: This doesn't help because I'm using Azure.

Comment: I tried to add multiple domains as well as the ip address with no luck. The requests are made from server side by C# HttpClient.

Comment: May be you haven't set HTTP Referer  correctly in your request. See this post for some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069912/here-maps-routing-api-fails-with-invalid-credentials-but-other-here-apis-conti

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. For future reference, it seems that the domain filter changes take about 1-2 hours to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed this problem by creating separate projects for frontend with domain limits and backend without.

Not an elegant solution, but it works, it's simple, and if I have to block a project in case someone hijacks the keys (everything sent through browser can be read by users) it's just some dynamic maps that wouldn't work until I update the site. Everything else is routed through the server.